# Parallel.Invoke wait until HttpClient Re-Login c#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, dotnet-httpclient, parallel.foreach

I am downloading some `pdf` files from a websites with `HttpClient`. I must login for see `pdf`'s `url`'s.

I am downloading all of pdf correctly without using `Parallel`. But this way is so slow.
I am using `Parallel.Invoke` for speed up this operations but its missing `authentication` sometimes. So I need to Re-login the website and continue to download pdf's and read it.

```
List<Action> actionList = new List<Action>();
foreach (var item in company.PayrollTables)
            {
                actionList.Add(new Action(() => SavePayroll(item, myHtppClient, company.ClientId, company.SubClientNo)));// Download pdf's
            }
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20 };
            Parallel.Invoke(options, actionList.ToArray());
```

---

```
  public void SavePayroll(PayrollTableModel model, BaseHttpClient webClient, int ClientId, string subClientNo)
        {
            try
            {
                var byteArray = webClient.GetByteArrayAsync(model.pdfDownloadUrl).Result;
                var isPdf = IsPdf(byteArray, model, subClientNo, ClientId);

                if (isPdf)
                {
                    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(byteArray))
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                        {
                            string thePage = "";
                            thePage = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i);
                            var table = GetEmployeeTable(thePage); // read existing page find table.

                            foreach (var row in table)
                            {

                               // read table nodes..                            
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // 
            }


        }
```

---

`myHtppClient` is common for all of Parallel actions.It must be. Because Website not allow multi-login.

In `SavePayroll` method, I am roaming between websites pages and finding correct Urls for download pdf and reading them with `ITextSharp` .

I am using `DownloadString` Method for change the pages for all of my request and  catch if logout or connection is still alive. If website sent me to login page so I am re-loggin again.

---

```
public DownloadStringResult DownloadString(string url)
{
    DownloadStringResult result = new DownloadStringResult();
    try
    {
        var html = base.GetStringAsync(url).Result; // base is HttpClient.
        if (html.Contains(WebSiteDto.LogoutMessage) || html.Contains("Please Login")) // Log-out website. So I need to re-login again.
        {
            result.IsRelogged = true;
            result.HtmlResult = GetLoginResult(); // re-login
            return result;
        }
        result.HtmlResult = html;
    }
    catch (Exception e) // This try catch for TimeOut Exception. I try many way but I still cant catch timeout exception. Or I cant tell wait just 5 second, if no answer then retry again.
    {
        return DownloadString(url);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Is there any way to tell all of Parallel Actions, "wait till one action re-login again.and then keep do your process." ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is `SavePayroll` related `DownloadString`?

Comment: I am usinng it like that. `myHtppClient.DownloadString(url);` Download string is a method which is under a class is inheritance from HtppClient

Comment: @FCin I am not using `DownloadString` method for download `pdf`. Its just for walk around between websites pages. But I can catch the logout in this `Method` then  re-login

Comment: Show what your `SavePayroll` method looks like.

Comment: @FCin I add the `SavePayroll` Method. Can you please check it again?

Comment: Why would the server just randomly log you out? Are you doing something you shouldn't be? ;)

Comment: No ;) @ToddMenier